# Rollup Summary not calculating in Test Setup

Tags: unit-test, roll-up-summary

I am at a loss. I've scoured this forum and others, but haven't figured out why this is happening. I'm re-querying and everything, yet the COUNT rollup is coming out as zero (expected is 1).

Field Name: OppsWithUsers__c
[image]

Code:

```
Id standardPricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

Opportunity testOpp1 = TestOpportunityFactory.createOpportunities(1, testAccount.Id)[0];
testOpp1.StageName = 'Prospecting';
testOpp1.Type = 'New';
testOpp1.Pricebook2Id = standardPricebookId;
testOpp1.OwnerId = salesUser.Id;
testOpp1.Contract_Start_Date__c = Date.today().addDays(-1);
testOpp1.Where_Are_Users__c = 'This Account Only';
testOpp1.Contract_Status_for_Rollup__c = 'Active';
testObjects2.add(testOpp1);

insert testObjects2;

testOpp1 = [SELECT Contract_Status_for_Rollup__c, Where_Are_Users__c, AccountId
            FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :testOpp1.Id];
Account updatedAcct = [SELECT OppsWithUsers__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :testOpp1.AccountId];

System.debug('status for rollup: '+testOpp1.Contract_Status_for_Rollup__c+' // where users: '+testOpp1.Where_Are_Users__c);
System.debug('updated OppsWithUsers: '+updatedAcct.OppsWithUsers__c);
```

Debug log:

> 11:38:39.73 (2870681429)|USER_DEBUG|[83]|DEBUG|status for rollup: Active // where users: This Account Only
>
> 11:49:18.65 (3188530801)|USER_DEBUG|[85]|DEBUG|updated OppsWithUsers: 0

Comment: Are you actually setting `testOpp1.AccountId`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, just didn't paste that part. I also realized I didn't paste the correct debug statement on the second System.debug, which I've since updated. That one would have errored if no Account was returned.

Comment: I have seen almost similar issues being discussed here or elsewhere, and some mentioned it worked while most of them not able to achieve as you have mentioned here. I wonder if this piece from the documentation has something to do with it - “Calculating roll-up summary field values can take up to 30 minutes...”.

Comment: What if you surround the `insert` with `startTest() / stopTest()` ?

Comment: @DavidCheng Didn't change anything :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was the API Name of the picklist field value. For some reason, the API Name had underscores. Thus, it wasn't satisfying the Roll-up Summary filter criteria.